# ID class CSS files

Tags: html, css, class, css-selectors

I'm having some difficulty with css and need some advice regarding classes and ID;s
I have two CSS files being called, one for **STYLING** and one for **DIV DIMENSIONS**

let's assume I have the following HTML header:

HTML

```
<div id="header" class="section">
```

CSS found in dimensions file

```
.section { 
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
```

CSS found in STYLING file

```
#header {   
    min-width: 50em;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #000; 
}
```

Are the following assumptions correct?

1) I assume a COMBINATION of the class and ID styles will apply to the header. however, the styles in the ID selector will take  precedence due to Specificity?
Therefore, if i define a width in the ID css, this will trump the 'class' css.

2) I assume you can use a combination of both class in css?

Many thanks,
Pete

Comment: And what is the question? Also, look at [Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

Comment: @pete Vucko answered pretty much your question. And yes, you can combine your selectors, but there's no need to combine both ID and CLASS for ID MUST be unique-per-page.

Comment: u can combine, http://jsfiddle.net/9c1kp552/, but u want to keep it clean, use Id's for practical purposes, for example to reference the object from javascript

Comment: Using both ids and class makes sense. OP can have multiple sections but only one header section.

Answer (score 1):

You should not split your styling and dimensions in different CSS files that makes it harder to overview your code and style.

You should generate classes for colors, appearance and stuff that can appear multiple times on your page so you can for example assign class="green" for as many elements as you like, even for dynamic contents without pasting a manual style tag.

Note:
A very good html page design does not contain any single raw "style" tag and does everything via css.

Everything else that only appears once on your website such as header, navigation and so on - elements omf the layout can get an ID assigned, yes.

But you should not split those in 2 CSS files as it is not nesessary except your project is really huge and complex.

For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #content {
        width: 300px;
    }
    .error {
        color: red;
    }
    .success {
        color: green;
    }
</style>

<div id="content"> <!-- Appears only once on your website -->
    <div class="error">Some error</div> <!-- Can appear multiple times -->
    <div class="error">Another error</div>  <!-- Can appear multiple times -->
    <div class="success">Some success message</div> <!-- Can appear multiple times -->
</div>
```

So to answer your question:

It is not nesessary, nor a good practice in general to mix both as you will override attributes and later wonder why your page looks broken, ugly or something like that!

Answer (score 0):

1. ID selector will take precedence due to Specificity - Yes
2. you can use a combination of both class in css - Yes

A simple fiddle can explain you better

http://jsfiddle.net/s8czntkn/

```
.section { 
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}
#header {   
    min-width: 10px;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100px;
    background: lightgrey; 
}
```